# Postman - How can I inflate and base64 decode a value? zlib or similar?

Tags: javascript, base64, postman, zlib

I have the following string that I need to inflate and base64 decode:

```
lZFNa8MwDIZ/jY8ejpxm29G0CxQ6GP3YYZfhJuoaSOzOdkq3Xz85bku39jIwMuiRXluvmBwzWR66loHYo/ONNUxOGEB2JyhSFk1l68Z8pPRqWfKHCGTJ5BMTiiqYHHvdtTsmlerD1szxs0cfiJCu8ZQ+4ijQO3pAWe2bCIzuMN6horBQzzO6gF6WaudssJVt0ycuhf6no71HF+JYg9B0ktrf66IuQALyAnTGcw05X9ew5qNsg/njRoiiyI8t3vc4NT5oE1IzCMi4GHG4X2bkhJIjChm8pfrXSxvhZOPUv9BXmj2m/Ea3HhMpratwMO4KTcjGxuhwltuGsItzMijpHFKVOo04tsb3HboFun1T4Wo+u9X1Nazv9+4IDmM6AsnZbyJU/BfGrjO42vjAfwA=
```

Anybody know how to do this in Postman?

I know in Javascript you can use zlib as shown below, but I don't think you can use zlib in Postman:

```
const zlib = require("zlib");
const example = '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'
const inflated = zlib.inflateRawSync(Buffer.from(example, 'base64')).toString('ascii');
console.log("Inflated:", inflated);
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no native support of zlib in postman. However, You may check if this way of loading third party modules help your case - 
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/734#issuecomment-70481732 
Try inflating it this way, base64 decoding is supported in postman.